# CSS3 new features...whats the point?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I've been reading a lot of ways recently of how to avoid having to use Photoshop for things like gradients and shadows on buttons, when you can use CSS3 Box Shadow for such features. Now this is great, but obviously legacy browsers and most IE browsers don't yet implement CSS3 features, so my question is, why save yourself extra work in Photoshop when you can use CSS3 but then HAVE to use Photoshop for other browsers to see the desired effects? Isn't that just extra work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> you can use CSS3 but then HAVE to use Photoshop for other browsers to see the desired effects?

Often you don't really care whether the other browsers see the desired effects. If it's just a subtle background gradient effect, the site's going to work fine and still look reasonable with a flat background in downlevel browsers.

Compatibility was more of a problem when CSS 2 Positioning was at this stage: an unsupported positioning feature could lead to an unusable layout. But for essentially frivolous effects like backgrounds, borders and shadows, it's not critical if the effect goes missing.

Comment: Agree.  The OP's assumption is wrong.  Special effects don't *have* to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons. From a developer/designers perspective, using CSS3 can be more flexible. An image is more or less just a static image. With CSS you can use script or CSS to animate or adjust the styling, and have advanced integration between the various technologies. This allows you to be able to do some things that are not possible or difficult just using images.

The page weight is also lower usually when using CSS, which allows the page to load faster, especially on slow connections or mobile devices. It also reduces HTTP requests (although you can use data uris too) which reduces latency and thus speeds up page loading.

Using CSS is often more maintainable and quicker, as you can adjust say a background colour or a shadow quickly just by changing the CSS, while with images you have to open up photoshop, edit the file, resave, etc. This is fantastic for quick tweaks.

There are also some people (myself included) that are much more comfortable in code than they are using graphics packages. For me it is easier to use CSS, but your milage may vary.

Also from the browser perspective we want to move the web platform forward and increase the capabilities. SVG is an example of another technology that doesn't work across all browser versions yet, but adds a lot of power. Although it may not be possible to deploy sites using certain CSS3 properties or SVG without fallbacks right now (depending on your audience or client) there will be a time in the future when old browsers are dead and what we are adding today works for all users. There was a time when most of CSS2.1 wasn't supported for example, while now you can rely on most of it if you don't need to design for IE6.

There are some parts of CSS3 that you can happily use without fallbacks, if you have a client that doesn't require all browsers to look the same. border-radius is an example, or giving a solid colour fallback to old browsers and applying transparency for newer browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The world is moving forward, you can't ignore it. as long as old browser will show a button and new browser will show a more nice one, you are ok.

Otherwise, we were still be working on VT100... as why using "Windows" if most monitors doesn't support more than 4 color graphics and has 80X22 resolution....

Comment: Whether or not this answer is applicable depends on if you interpret the question as asking "what's the point of these features even being added" or "what's the point of *me* taking advantage of these new features". Certainly the world has to move forward, and that's why the CSS3 specification included the new features. But just as most people didn't upgrade to Windows immediately because it didn't support the existing installed base of hardware very well and often proved to be more trouble than it was worth, the same with why it might not be worth replacing Photoshop with CSS3 effects yet.

Comment: i'm fine with moving forward (i would rather use new features) :)

Comment: Well, we used to have a commercial around here.. if you don't move forward, you move backwards. So for now you might be right, but in 2 years, new sites will look better and load faster, and yours might not. So - IMHO - I'm always trying to use the latest tech available...

Answer (score 0):

If your bosses accepts the idea of having two versions of looks and feel and a warning. CSS3 is a good idea.

So, you use CSS3 features in your code and forget about the browsers that are not compatible -- they will see the "low-graphics version", you might want to issue a non-intrusive warning (like the one we get as alerts in StackOverflow), saying, `"Your browser is not compatible with CSS3. To see this website in high graphics please upgrade your browser. Click the link here to update now."`

But, depends on where you work. Big companies with lot of resources may like to stick with Photoshop and smaller once may like a light-weight CSS3 code that degrades silently in non-compatible browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always use ChromeFrame, to impose nice behavior on IE. Assuming that a lot of products will insist for it the near future (yeah we can argue against this), chances are that most IE users will have chromeFrame even before your application would insist for it. Once you take a decision on this, decision on using CSS3 properties or HTML5 elements is - well - hell yeah!!

- Marvin